# Best way to make a multi activity app in android

Tags: android, performance, list, android-activity, usability

I'm trying to make an application for android that consist in multiple choices, each one depending on the previous one.

At first, a list with some options is displayed, after choosing one, I send a petition to a webserver database and send back the new options and create a new activity with the new options and so on till the last list of options.

I use asynctask for the petition sending and use putExtra to send the information between activities.

The problem is that I don't like this approach. Too many activities and cycling through them is a pain, and when the last option is chosen, I would like to go back to the main screen but I have a bunch of activities to handle first and I dunno how to do it.

Any idea I'm missing of how to approach this problem? Is possible to reuse the same activity? Each option is packed differenly as the databse query is different.

Any help would be welcome :)

Comment: "Petition?" Do you mean an HTTP request?

Comment: Yes, I use HttpClient in an Asynctask to send a JSON package to the server and wait for a reply

Comment: It seems it was an strange question. At least I would like to know if there is a way to close all previous activities after one point and begin a new activity to continue the flow of the application :S